# What is the shape/order of points expected by CV2 plotChessboardCorners and cornersSubPix?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to pass an array of points to the plotChessboardCorners and cornersSubPix functions, but I'm getting these error messages:

```
Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibinit.cpp:1944:
error: (-215) nelems >= 0 in function cv::drawChessboardCorners

Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\cornersubpix.cpp:257: 
error: (-215) ncorners >= 0 && corners.depth() == CV_32F in function cv::cornerSubPix
```

which I think have to do with the ordering of the array. However, findChessboardCorners returns an array of shape [npoints, 1, 2], which is the same as the shape of the array I'm passing?

My code is:

```
                if (findChessboardCorners failed):
                    corners = (reconstructed corners of shape [npoints, 2])
                    corners.shape = (len(corners),1,2) #reshape to shape expected by openCV
                    numfound = 0 if corners is None else len(corners) 

                    if numfound==nX*nY: #reconstruction successful
                        figC = plt.figure('Corners found in image ' +str(i+1) + ' in camera ' +camnames[j])                
                        plt.imshow(I, cmap='gray')
                        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(Inew, (nX,nY), corners, 1)
                        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a datatype issue: the corners array needs to be float32.
The error message was being generated by this assert statement:
`int nelems = corners.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true);
CV_Assert(nelems >= 0);`